# How can you extract gene names from overlapping gene lists

Tags: r

I currently have a script looking at the gene overlap between different gene lists. So what the code returns is an eight by eight matrix with the different number of genes found overlapping (i.e. common to both lists). Is there a way I can look at these specific genes and find out the gene symbols for them?

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set the working directory and load the data files
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setwd("~/Desktop/R_Project/Gene_overlap")
getwd()
files <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
files

data.list <- lapply(files, function(fil) {
  scan(file=fil, what=character())
})

names(data.list) <- basename(files) %>% stringr::str_remove("\\.txt$")

str(data.list)
# List of 8
# $ GSE108363_BCGdown_D:chr [1:350] "IL1B" "IL6" "IL1A" "CCL20" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGdown_V: chr [1:267] "IL6" "CCL20" "IL1A" "CXCL5" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGup_D  : chr [1:250] "FABP4" "CMTM2" "FUCA1" "CD36" ...
# $ GSE108363_BCGup_V  : chr [1:429] "FCN1" "FCGR3B" "MNDA" "CPVL" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBdown_D: chr [1:86] "CCL20" "IL1B" "IL1A" "IL6" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBdown_V: chr [1:244] "IL1B" "IL1A" "CCL20" "IL6" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBup_D  : chr [1:128] "FUCA1" "FGL2" "TGFBI" "CPVL" ...
# $ GSE108363_MTBup_V  : chr [1:286] "FABP4" "RNASE1" "MNDA" "CPVL" ...

intersect(data.list$GSE108363_BCGdown_D, data.list$GSE108363_BCGdown_V) %>% length

sapply(data.list, length)



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Using the intersect function to see the overlaps 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data.file1 <- "GSE108363_BCGdown_D.txt"
data.file2 <- "GSE108363_BCGdown_V.txt"
data.file3 <- "GSE108363_BCGup_D.txt"
data.file4 <- "GSE108363_BCGup_V.txt"
data.file5 <- "GSE108363_MTBdown_D.txt"
data.file6 <- "GSE108363_MTBdown_V.txt"
data.file7 <- "GSE108363_MTBup_D.txt"
data.file8 <- "GSE108363_MTBup_V.txt"

genevect1 <- scan(data.file1, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect2 <- scan(data.file2, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect3 <- scan(data.file3, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect4 <- scan(data.file4, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect5 <- scan(data.file5, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect6 <- scan(data.file6, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect7 <- scan(data.file7, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect8 <- scan(data.file8, what=character(), sep="\n")


filelist <- list(data.file1, data.file2, data.file3, data.file4, data.file5, data.file6, data.file7, data.file8)
all(sapply(filelist, file.exists))

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# read files:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

gene.lists <- lapply(filelist, function(f) {
  scan(file=f, what=character())
})


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# set up empty matrix for overlaps
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x <- (length(gene.lists))^2
x
y <- rep(NA, x)
mx <- matrix(y, ncol=length(gene.lists))
mx
row.names(mx) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
colnames(mx) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
mx

mx.overlap.count <- mx

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Overlaps
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for (i in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
  g1 <- gene.lists[[i]]
  for (j in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
    g2 <- gene.lists[[j]]
    a <- intersect(g1, g2)
    b <- length(a)
    mx.overlap.count[j,i] <- b
  }
}

mx.overlap.count
round(as.numeric(mx.overlap.count),digits = 1)
View(mx.overlap.count)
```

At the moment, this code returns numerical values. However, I would like to generate some sort of list for each two gene lists being compared (or something similar) so that I can look to see exactly which genes were common to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve the problem by looping through a matrix of contrasts, storing the length of the intersection in a matrix like you've done, and storing the gene names in a list, `genes.overlap`. Like this:

```
# Load files. 
file_names <- list.files(pattern=".txt")

# Extract gene lists. 
gene.lists <- lapply(file_names, function(f) {
  scan(file=f, what=character())
})

# Name the entries in the list. 
names(gene.lists) <- file_names
names(gene.lists)

# Initiate an empty list and matrix for storing output of loop.
genes.overlap <- list()
nfiles <- length(gene.lists)
mx.overlap.count <- matrix(NA,nrow=nfiles)

# Generate contrasts:
contrasts <- combn(nfiles,2)

# Loop to determine intersection:
for (i in 1:dim(contrasts)[2]){
  list1 <- contrasts[1,i]
  list2 <- contrasts[2,i]
  g1 <- gene.lists[[list1]]
  g2 <- gene.lists[[list2]]
  comparison_name <- paste(names(gene.lists[list1]),names(gene.lists[list2]),sep="_")
  genes.overlap[[i]] <- intersect(g1, g2)
  names(genes.overlap)[i] <- comparison_name
  b <- length(genes.overlap[[i]])
  mx.overlap.count[i] <- b
}

# You can index into a list like a df with the $ operator. 
genes.overlap$List.txt_List1.txt
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution but I am not sure why it is not working. I copied this code to my script. At the end of it when I View(b) i get 104 which is actually a value for one of the overlap between a couple of my gene lists but I am not getting the result I was after. Any chance of me emailing you the gene lists to see the issue?

Comment: I put two lists (List1 and List2) on my GitHub: https://github.com/twesleyb/getPPIs. The lists are Entrez gene ID's but, that shouldn't matter. Let me know if you can't figure it out!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing that, it seems like this code has done the job! I am now able to see all the gene symbols in the console which is great. Is there a way of viewing which genes have come from which overlap? Your input is much appreciated

Comment: You can add names to lists. I edited my answer so you could see how this might be done.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. My eight gene lists were already previously defined as: BCGdown_D, BCGdown_V, MTBdown_D, MTBdown_V etc with the other four being the same but with 'up' instead of 'down'. Is there a way to use these names?

Comment: The code above should provide an example of how to do that.

Comment: I was also just thinking, with each overlap between two gene lists being compared at a time, it is not possible to store all the gene symbols in a matrix because of the vast number of gene symbols that exist? Could you possibly recommend a good way of representing the overlapping genes, making it clear which two gene lists they come from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187900/discussion-between-twb10-and-h-a).